# How to convert a numeric value into a Date value

Tags: r

So, I have a data.frame with a column called Date.birth, but I have these values in a numeric format:

```
Date.birth
43067
43060
```

Probably is problem format. But I need in a Date format like these:

```
Date.birth
11/28/17
11/21/17
```

Actually the above format is the correct. I tried this command:

```
as.Date(levels(data$Date.birth), format="%d.%m.%Y")
```

but didn't work. Anyone has a suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Look for the Tag! It's R platform.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We need to specify the origin if it is a `numeric` value

```
as.Date(data$Date.birth, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

e.g.

```
as.Date(43067, origin = "1899-12-30")
#[1] "2017-11-28"
```

After converting to `Date` class, if it needs to be in a custom format, use `format`

```
format(as.Date(43067, origin = "1899-12-30"), "%m/%d/%y")
#[1] "11/28/17"
```

If your column is factor, do convert to numeric first

```
as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(data$Date.birth)), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun, but didn't work. This message appears:
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @GregCurious Hmm, because your column is `factor`, do convert to `numeric` first, `as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(data$Date.birth, origin = "1899-12-30")`

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: @JennaLeaf it is `R`

Comment: Oh, I saw it, now.  The 'r' !!

Answer (score 4):

If this is an excel numeric date, `janitor` has a great solution:

```
library(janitor)

excel_numeric_to_date(data$Date.birth)
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be simply done by using `lubridate` package-

```
lubridate::as_date(as.numeric(dt$Date.birth),origin="1899-12-30")  
[1] "2017-11-28" "2017-11-21"
```

**Sample Data-**

```
dt <- read.table(text="Date.birth
43067
43060",header=T)
```

Comment: I tried this to, but this message appears:
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
 
In my data.frame I have 'NA' values. Can be a problem to use this?

Comment: @GregCurious  as I suggested in the comments, your column is `factor` and needs to be converteed to `numeric`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
VariableName <- dt %>% 
mutate(Date.birth = format(excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(Date.birth)),"%m/%d/%y"))
#[1] "11/28/17"
```